# Using context in twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I try to use `twisted.python.context`, but context disappear after first `deferToThread`.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer, threads
from twisted.python import context

def _print_context(msg):
    cont = context.get('cont')
    print "{msg}: {context}".format(msg=msg, context=cont)

def sub_call():
    _print_context("In sub_call")

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def with_context():
    _print_context("before thread")
    yield threads.deferToThread(sub_call)
    _print_context("after thread")
    reactor.stop()

def test():
    cont = {'cont': "TestContext"}
    context.call(cont, with_context)
reactor.callLater(0, test)
reactor.run()
```

I have context before `deferToThread` and in `sub_call`, but no context after `deferToThread`.

Is there any way to have context after `deferToThread`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`context.call` sets the context for the duration of the call of the object passed to it - in this case `with_context`.

`with_context` is an `inlineCallbacks`-wrapped generator function.  The first call to it creates a new generator and iterates it as far as the first `yield` statement.  Then its execution is suspended and, as far as the caller is concerned, the call returns.  At this point the context stack is popped and the context you supplied is discarded.

Later, the implementation of `inlineCallbacks` ensures the generator will be iterated further so that the code after the `yield` statement executes.  However, the context has already been discarded.

There's no easy way to fix this.  `twisted.python.context` does not try to address the problem of **asynchronous** context management.  Moreover, `twisted.python.context` is fairly terrible and few if any programs should actually be written to use it.

I recommend taking a step back and re-evaluating your choice here.  You'd probably be better served by creating a class and using instance attributes on an instance of it to carry state around between method calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ofcourse  I use classes, this was just a minimal example of problem. But only solution that I see, is to pass context in methods params. I don't like this solution, but can't find any other.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't like the solution of passing the inputs to your methods as parameters.

Comment: @Glyph, Because it is an optional parameter, that will present in each methods, most of this methods don't need this parameter, they don't even have to know that one exist, they must just pass it to the next methods. In this parameter I pass info about user who perform action on the system. And `context`, I think is the best solution to solve this problem.

Comment: But... it's not optional. It's an input that the method needs to do its job, or you could just give a default parameter with a value of `None` :).  So the issue is that you have some code on the outside that needs to know about this parameter, and many layers of code in the middle which need to do nothing but pass it on down?

Comment: @Glyph, Yes, that is what I have now, many methods with parameter `context=None` and many layers that usually don't need it.